# Dragging and dropping controls in Objective C (iOS)

Tags: objective-c, ios

This is my first question on Stack Overflow, after reading many results from Googling various programming problems.

My question is about iOS development.
Basically I have a button that, when pressed, creates another button on the view. I want the user to be able to drag that button around the form. From searching, I found code that shows how to move a button, but that requires having an outlet connected to it (so you can set the center property). Since the button has been created programatically in another method, I can't figure out how to set the center property.

Here's my addButton: method:

```
-(IBAction)addButton:(id)sender{
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(5.0, 25.0, 40.0, 40.0);
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(moveButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
[button setTitle:@"Test Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = frame;
[myView addSubview:button];
```

}

And what I have typed into the touchesMoved: method:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
```

}

I'm pretty new to iOS development, so I'm not really sure how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

You should make the second button a property of your class. First declare the property in the .h+.m file just like the first one was automatically by xCode. Then at the end of your example code add self.secondButtonPropertyNameHere = button;

Once it's a property of the class, any method can set it's properties.

Edit:

Instead of a UIButton property make an NSMutableArray property. Then just add the new button to the array so you can keep a reference to them. Just remember if you go to remove one call [buttonToRemove removeFromSuperview] and remove from the array.

Edit(2):

Your initial question was about making a second button and moving it around. The property of UIButton will work well for that. Because you're moving one object on the view receiving the touches* events. If I were you I would stick with this approach until you are comfortable with the touches* events.

When you are ready to move on. You can manage multiple runtime created UIViews (in your case you want to use buttons) you have to choices:

1) In the touchesBegan: of your view controller iterate thru your array of buttons to see if perhaps the touch fell on one of them and then track the touch until the touchesEnded: call.

2) Subclass the UIView and let it handle it's own touches* events.

The second is much easier to manage.

Edit(3):
You will need to set `[button setUserInteractionEnabled:NO]` if you wish the superview to handle the touches* events instead of the buttons.

Comment: This looks like what I was looking for. Although one problem I can see is that, if I try to make more than one new button with the same method, it would set the same property again instead of creating a new one. Is there some way to automatically increment the property name?

Comment: Edit in response to OP comment.

Comment: (I couldn't edit my previous comment, it kept saying I could only edit every 5 seconds...)
I added it to the array, but now I'm not sure how to actually move it. I set a method for TouchDragInside (and called it moveButton) but I'm not sure where to go from here. I think I have to somehow use the touchesMoved method but how do I pass the sender from the moveButton method to the touchesMoved method?

Comment: Edit(2) in response to OP comment

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I was able to drag the button around (not quite in the way I wanted, you have to click and drag off of the button or it wont work, but it's a good start). I'll have to look into the more advanced topic you talked about in the 2nd edit.

Comment: I can't see your code but I assume the button is waiting to see if you will touchUpInside: or not first.

Comment: I mean, if you try dragging the actual button it doesn't work, so instead you have to click somewhere not on the button and start dragging and it'll jump to the touch point. I'm assuming because I'm using the touchesMoved method and not using a method for dragging the actual button.

Comment: Edit (3) in response to comment.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar, but in a different way: you can create buttons, then move them around in a rect (actually a scaled view of the later real sized view) and change the size too, with 4 sliders and other buttons for fine tuning. It's very simple by just setting the frame of the target button to new values all the time. I didn't do it with dragging because the button could get too small for the finger.